# A word to use in articles to mean a chapter for additional content

Tags: meaning, word-usage, writing

I am creating an article.  I have chapters such as Objective, Preamble, Assumptions, Instructions. I need to add a chapter for some things that are out of the article essence but related to and important.

I have found some words in a vocabulary:

> addition additive supplement accompaniment addendum appendix appurtenance perk perquisite adjunct affixture allowance capper dope suggestion topping add-on
>   replenishment addition complement completion pendant pendent

I get the feeling that `supplement, appendix, add-on or completion` would fit.
Wouldn't they? Which should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why so many people are voting to close this.  It seems like a perfectly acceptable "what is the best word to describe this thing?" type of question, of which we get many.

For written materials, a common term for *additional, but not required content* is "appendix":

> **[appendix](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appendix)** (n): 2. A section or table of subsidiary matter at the end of a book or document.

An appendix usually contains a substantial amount of pertinent information, but supplemental to the main story.  For example in his book "The Lord of the Rings", J.R.R. Tolkien includes a number of *appendices* on the history of the world he created, and of the languages he created for that world.  You don't have to read these appendices to enjoy the story, but they are quite detailed and of interest to some readers.

If instead you just want to include a "note" at the end of the document (which can be quite long), then you can call it an [*addendum*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addendum) or [*afterword*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afterword). [*Supplement*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplement) may be fine, although this usually implies something added after the document has been published, and which makes up for something lacking in the original.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential term for such a chapter could be "excursus".

[**Merriam-Webster definition of "excursus":**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excursus)

> an appendix or digression that contains further exposition of some
>   point or topic